# EMF or terminal voltage and current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

What will be the current circuit and terminal voltage?

1. if we connect terminals of an ideal cells  with an external wire of no resistance?
2. if we connect terminals of  cell with some internal resistance with an external wire of no resistance?

Comment: If we connect two things that don't exist, then we get a third non-existing thing, I am afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Ideal voltage sources and zero resistance wire are conceptual devices used for circuit analysis only.  If you put this problem into a circuit simulator, such as spice, it should throw an error as you have requested a division by zero (by ohm's law). Try it!